# How to juggle between windows (game and pause window) in ncurses?

Tags: c, window, ncurses, pause, game-loop

I am creating a game in C. I'm not playing it in stdscr, but in a win called `basewin`. I want, when the user press 'P', to open another window, called `pausewin`, and pause the game running on `basewin`. Then, when the user press 'R' for resume, I want to "close" `pausewin`, and get my game resumes. Especially, I want to see my `basewin` in the same state I left it before pressing 'P'.

I was thinking I can do that by using window because:

1. It would make my code cleaner.
2. Windows are pointer on memory space, so I can restore `basewin` easily.
3. It will be a general method to pause any game, without getting trouble with `printw` after quitting `pausewin`.

But my idea didn't work. I tried this on a simplified game:

```c
#include <ncurses.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
    
int main() {
    /* INIT NCURSES */ 
    initscr(); 
    curs_set(0); 
    noecho();
    
    /* INIT PAUSE WIN */
    WINDOW *pausewin = newwin(LINES/3, COLS/3,LINES/3, COLS/3);
    keypad(pausewin,TRUE);
    int cMax_pause, lMax_pause; getmaxyx(pausewin,lMax_pause, cMax_pause);
    box(pausewin,0,0);
    mvwprintw(pausewin,1,cMax_pause/2 -5,"PAUSE WIN");
    mvwprintw(pausewin,lMax_pause/2, cMax_pause/3-4, "[R]ESUME");
    mvwprintw(pausewin,lMax_pause/2, 2*cMax_pause/3-3, "[Q]UIT");
    
    /* INIT BASE WIN */
    WINDOW *basewin = newwin(LINES, COLS/2, 0, COLS/4);
    keypad(basewin,TRUE);
    int lMax, cMax; getmaxyx(basewin, lMax, cMax);
    box(basewin,0,0);
    mvwprintw(basewin,0,2, "[P]AUSE");
    mvwprintw(basewin,1,cMax/2 -4,"BASE WIN");
    
    /* INIT VAR */
    bool loop = true;
    bool pause = false;
    int ch,chp;
    
    /* INIT VARS PLAYER */
    int pline = lMax/2;
    int pcol = cMax/2;
    char pch[2] ; pch[0] = 'M';
    
    /* AFFICHAGE BASE WIN : PRE-LOOP */
    wrefresh(basewin);
    
    /* "GAME" LOOP */
    while(loop){
        
        ch = wgetch(basewin);
        switch(ch){
            case 'p': /* On met le jeu en pause */
            case 'P':
                pause = true;
                break;
            case KEY_LEFT: /* Sinon deplacement */
                pcol -= 1;
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                pcol += 1;
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                pline -= 1;
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                pline += 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    
    if (pause){
        wrefresh(pausewin);  // HERE IS THE PLACE I HAVE MY PROBLEM
        while(pause){
            chp = wgetch(pausewin);
            switch (chp){
            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
                pause = false;
                loop = false;
                break;
            case 'r':
            case 'R':
                pause = false;
                wrefresh(basewin); // HERE TOO
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    else{
        mvwprintw(basewin,pline,pcol,pch);
    }
    
    wrefresh(basewin);
    }
    
    
    delwin(pausewin);
    delwin(basewin);
    endwin();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have a relatively good comprehension of ncurses manual, but I can't get this working.
I tried to solve that with a `tempwin`, but it work one time and then never print `pausewin` again.
I also tried to use `overwrite()` but it doesn't really look like the good way to solve that.

Comment: By the way, in `char pch[2] ; pch[0] = 'M';`, `pch[1]` remains an *uninitialized*, *indeterminate* value. If this value happens to be anything other than the zero byte, you will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when using this array as a *string* (e.g., with `mvwprintw`). Prefer `char pch[] = "M";` to create a string.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach would be to call [`touchwin`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/touchwin.html) to indicate that the entire window should be redrawn to the screen.

(*Note that `wgetch(pausewin)` implies `wrefresh(pausewin)` when the window has been modified [in this case marked as such by `touchwin`], otherwise `wrefresh` must be called to actually produce output. `wrefresh(basewin)` is called at the bottom of the main loop, regardless of the pause.*)

```
if (pause) {
    touchwin(pausewin);

    while (pause) {
        chp = wgetch(pausewin);

        switch (chp) {
            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
                pause = false;
                loop = false;
                break;
            case 'r':
            case 'R':
                pause = false;
                touchwin(basewin);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```